# Inconsistent Golang behavior between VSCode and CLI

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, operator-sdk, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I'm working with [operator-sdk](https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk) and am seeing inconsistent behavior between VSCode and the CLI.

When I run with `operator-sdk run --local` I see the below. But VSCode shows no errors. I'm not really sure why that might be or where the problem is.

```
pkg/controller/mypackage/mycontroller_controller.go:207:4: cannot use testRef (type *"github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/apis/pipeline/v1alpha1".PipelineRef) as type "github.com/tektoncd/pipeline/pkg/apis/pipeline/v1alpha1".PipelineRef in field value
```

The code in question looks like this.

```golang
    //...declaration
    testRef := &tekton.PipelineRef{
        Name: "mypipeline",
    }
    //..usage later...
    Spec: tekton.PipelineRunSpec{
            PipelineRef: testRef,
            Params: []tekton.Param{{
```

I'm using gomodules, and the relevant module is -> `github.com/tektoncd/pipeline v0.10.0`

I understand that this is something to do with pointer referencing, and when I change my code to

```golang
testRef := tekton.PipelineRef{
        Name: "mypipeline",
    }
```

Then VSCode shows an error like below, but the CLI doesn't report any errors.

```
cannot use testRef (variable of type v1alpha1.PipelineRef) as *v1alpha1.PipelineRef value in struct literal
```

Is this just a module dependency problem and my upstream API changed somewhere? Maybe my cli and VSCode are reading different dependencies? I don't even know where to start... Any pointers (pun intended) are appreciated.

Comment: I'm only guessing (I prefer goland for its much much better debugger integration) but this looks like the cli and vscode are resolving different versions of a dependent library. Does VSCode have a setting to turn on gomodule support / vendoring?

Comment: @Keynan - same behavior is observed in goland. Looking for tips on how exactly I could track down the dependency issues.

Comment: in goland you can search actions (Ctrl + Shift + A) for vendor mode

Comment: definitely dependency resolution issue, just developing in vscode containers resolved.